# Mailman sends list emails from mylist-bounce address

Tags: postfix, mailman

I've configured mailman with postfix in 2 different ways and in both of them, when I send an email to the list (ex: **mylist@lists.example.com**), all the subscribers receive the email from "**mylist-bounces@mylists.example.com**". I don't know why the "**-bounces**" in the From address, so I've setup a "Reply-To" header so that the reply goes to the list email (not to -bounces), but I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Sending an email to the list from a valid subscriber, ends in receiving correctly the email, but from mylist-bounces@, not from mylist@:

```
Jan 13 09:56:09 server postfix/qmgr[17951]: C694C20A2EEE: from=<user@example.com>, size=2299, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 13 09:56:10 server postfix/smtpd[18049]: disconnect from mail-qg0-f54.google.com
Jan 13 09:56:10 server postfix/pipe[18054]: C694C20A2EEE: to=<mylist@lists.example.com>, relay=mailman, delay=0.72, delays=0.52/0.02/0/0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via mailman service)
Jan 13 09:56:10 server postfix/qmgr[17951]: C694C20A2EEE: removed
Jan 13 09:56:11 server postfix/smtpd[18049]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 13 09:56:11 server postfix/smtpd[18049]: 7AFC720A2EEE: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 13 09:56:11 server postfix/cleanup[18053]: 7AFC720A2EEE: message-id=<CACUG7ke_xq6w2FM+2KCC_wyENBfM7h7o-7iAuydi4R_+9tb=Yg@mail.gmail.com>
Jan 13 09:56:11 server postfix/qmgr[17951]: 7AFC720A2EEE: from=<mylist-bounces@lists.example.com>, size=3782, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 13 09:56:11 server postfix/smtpd[18049]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 13 09:56:12 server postfix/smtp[18056]: 7AFC720A2EEE: to=<user@example.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25, delay=0.71, delays=0.01/0.04/0.07/0.59, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1421139372 4si40583259wjv.55 - gsmtp)
Jan 13 09:56:12 server postfix/qmgr[17951]: 7AFC720A2EEE: removed
```

These are the email headers:

```
Delivered-To: user@example.com
Received: by X.Y.Z.X with SMTP id e107csp383549qge;
        Tue, 13 Jan 2015 02:40:25 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by A.B.C.D with SMTP id d16mr4467352wiw.77.1421145624883;
        Tue, 13 Jan 2015 02:40:24 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <mylist-bounces@lists.example.com>
Received: from myserver.example.com (myserver.example.com)
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id un10si40938267wjc.103.2015.01.13.02.40.24
        for <user@example.com>;
        Tue, 13 Jan 2015 02:40:24 -0800 (PST)
Received: from myserver.example.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by myserver.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id B49BD20A3379
    for <user@example.com>; Tue, 13 Jan 2015 11:40:23 +0100 (CET)
Subject: [mylist] test
X-BeenThere: mylist@lists.example.com
X-Mailman-Version: 2.1.15
Precedence: list
Reply-To: mylist@lists.example.com
List-Id: <mylist.lists.example.com>
List-Unsubscribe: <http://lists.example.com/mailman/options/mylist>, 
 <mailto:mylist-request@lists.example.com?subject=unsubscribe>
List-Post: <mailto:mylist@lists.example.com>
List-Help: <mailto:mylist-request@lists.example.com?subject=help>
List-Subscribe: <http://lists.example.com/mailman/listinfo/mylist>, 
 <mailto:mylist-request@lists.example.com?subject=subscribe>
Errors-To: mylist-bounces@lists.example.com
Sender: "mylist" <mylist-bounces@lists.example.com>
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 11:40:23 +0100 (CET)
From: mylist-bounces@lists.example.com
```

The list configuration:

```
root@myserver: /usr/lib/mailman/bin # ./config_list -o temp mylist

root@myserver: /usr/lib/mailman/bin # grep -vE "^#|^$" temp
real_name = 'mylist'
owner = ['user@example.com']
moderator = []
subject_prefix = '[mylist] '
anonymous_list = False
first_strip_reply_to = False
reply_goes_to_list = 1
reply_to_address = ''
umbrella_list = False
umbrella_member_suffix = '-owner'
send_reminders = True
admin_immed_notify = True
admin_notify_mchanges = False
respond_to_post_requests = True
new_member_options = 256
administrivia = True
max_message_size = 10240
admin_member_chunksize = 30
host_name = 'lists.example.com'
include_rfc2369_headers = 1
include_list_post_header = 1
include_sender_header = 1
preferred_language = 'en'
available_languages = ['en']
encode_ascii_prefixes = 0
nondigestable = True
scrub_nondigest = False
regular_exclude_lists = []
regular_exclude_ignore = True
regular_include_lists = []
digestable = True
digest_is_default = False
mime_is_default_digest = False
advertised = 1
subscribe_policy = 3
unsubscribe_policy = 1
ban_list = []
private_roster = 1
obscure_addresses = 1
default_member_moderation = False
member_moderation_action = 0
member_moderation_notice = ''
generic_nonmember_action = 1
forward_auto_discards = True
nonmember_rejection_notice = ''
require_explicit_destination = 0
acceptable_aliases = ''
max_num_recipients = 10
header_filter_rules = []
bounce_matching_headers = """
to: friend@public.com
message-id: relay.comanche.denmark.eu
from: list@listme.com
from: .*@uplinkpro.com"""
bounce_processing = True
bounce_score_threshold = 5.0
bounce_info_stale_after = 7
bounce_you_are_disabled_warnings = 3
bounce_you_are_disabled_warnings_interval = 7
bounce_unrecognized_goes_to_list_owner = True
bounce_notify_owner_on_disable = True
bounce_notify_owner_on_removal = True
autorespond_postings = 0
autoresponse_postings_text = ''
autorespond_admin = 0
autoresponse_admin_text = ''
autorespond_requests = 0
autoresponse_request_text = ''
autoresponse_graceperiod = 90
collapse_alternatives = True
convert_html_to_plaintext = True
filter_action = 0
topics_enabled = 0
topics_bodylines_limit = 5
topics = []
```

EDIT: I'm removing the postfix config as it seems to be ok
(snipped)

Could anybody give me a clue on what is wrong in the above config for the list to send the emails from that FROM address?

Comment: Good idea, it was a quick %s/mydomain/domain for the question text, but yes, it's better to use example.com :). Thanks for fixing it in the question text.

Comment: I'm migrating email from a shared hosting (with Cpanel + mailman) to my own VPS (CentOS 7, postfix, mailman). In the old hosting, emails sent to mylist@lists.example.com are sent to the list subscribers with "From: <mylist@lists.example.com>", not with "From: <mylist-bounces@lists.example.com>" ... But, then ... it is OK to receive the email from mylist-bounce??? :-?

Comment: Usually email has two kinds of sender address, address in envelope sender and address in `From:` header. The address that you see in maillog was envelope sender. **Usually** MUA should show the `From:` header. *And by default Mailman set envelope sender with listname-bounces@lists.example.com and **doesn't modify From: header***

Comment: In my case, in the headers of the email received (as seen in "Show original", in gmail) I have the Return-Path:, the From: and the Sender: email headers all 3 set to "mylist-bounces@lists.example.com". So Gmail shows the message in the Inbox coming from "-bounces", but I was expecting that the From is "mylist@" ... I would like the From to show mylist@lists.example.com (if possible). I'm adding a Reply-To header that ensures that replying the message points to the right list email address and not to -bounce, but that was not needed in the old hosting mailman config ... Thanks for your patience

Comment: The config for the actual lists would help; the postfix config doesn't help much here. You can get this config by running `config_list ` from within `/path/to/mailman/bin`. (Also - thanks a **lot** for changing to example.com!)

Comment: Updated with the config_list output and removed the "postfix" config (as it seems to be OK).

Comment: I think I know what's going on. If mailman cannot find a valid From: header, it adds mylist-bounces@ as the From header. Doing "telnet 25" tests, without a From header (just Subject: after a DATA), I get the -bounces. Sending emails from a MUA (Gmail), it shows the "sender" From header. I can assume that nobody will try to send an email to the list with a From so nobody will see the "-bounces" email address, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK: I think I know what's going on. If mailman cannot find a valid From: header, it adds mylist-bounces@ as the From header.

Doing "telnet 25" tests, without a From header (just Subject: after a DATA), I get the -bounces.

Sending emails from a MUA (Gmail), it shows the "sender" From header. I can assume that nobody will try to send an email to the list with a From so nobody will see the "-bounces" email address, right?

Thanks a lot, @masegaloeh , for pointing me to the answer :).